# Bind to non-existing/inheritance node in object tree

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, tree

I currently face a problem which i cannot solve in my head ... so i come here in hope that one of you sees the solution i currently seek ...

## Situation

I got an object tree i generated out of a "custom" file format which supports inheritance (parent can be anywhere in current or upper scopes)

**THIS IS NO C# or pseudo code :)**

```
class foo
{
    a = "foobar";
};
class container
{
    class bar
    {
        b = "foobar";
    };
    class fooExtension : foo
    {
        //contains 'a' with value "foobar"
        b = "foo";
    };
};
```

(for those wondering, yes this is from the game [ArmA](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Config))

This now results in following "access keys"

```
/foo
/foo/as
/container
/container/bar
/container/bar/b
/container/fooExtension/b
```

Plus the derived key `/container/fooExtension/a` that exists only because `fooExtension` has `foo` as parent

That object tree can be browsed using:

- `GetKey(string, AccessTypeEnum)` Provides maximum control about single key targets
- `[int]` gets single child node
- `[int, int]` gets a range of child nodes
- `[string]` checks object tree for given string-key using GetKey

The class representing each node implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `INotifyPropertyChanging` and `IEnumerable<ConfigField>`

events are not bubbeling the tree up

## Problem

I want to bind to `/container/fooExtension/a` or to `/Some/Not/Existing/Key` without creating the node (as that would break up with the inheritance) and without creating a whole observer class around the node tree (as that is a nightmare to maintain & implement properly)

## Current thoughts

This problem now bothers me the whole weekend ... the solution i came up with are all garbage (Creating a new `Binding` class to subscribe to the correct parents) or a nightmare to implement (observer class, "reference" object observing the highest available key, ...)

## Finally

any chance somebody has a magic trick laying around here somewhere?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you explain this in C# terms? Is this a tree of dictionaries? Are you saying you want to bind to keys that don't exist? Your odd pseudocode is a bit of a red herring if that's the case; it might be better to focus more on the concrete implementation details and not so much on the semantics; this question seems unrelated to inheritance in C#. At first I thought you didn't understand how classes work.

Comment: If I didn't need many change notifications going to the ui, I would bind to the root of the dictionary tree and pass the item path as a ConverterParameter to a value converter. The converter can fake up nonexistent keys. If you need a lot of PropertyChanged, maybe write a class that implements IDictionary and INotifyPropertyChanged. Give it an internal dictionary, *and* some semi-clever hack to fake up imaginary keys.

Comment: @EdPlunkett there is no pseudo code whatsoever in this question
the provided "code" is the actual file structure
The implementation works with simple objects that have a Children List and a WeakReference object that points to their parents

[full implementation can be found here](https://github.com/X39/ArmA-UI-Editor/blob/ParserRecreation/ArmAClassParser/SQF/ClassParser/ConfigField.cs)

Comment: @EdPlunkett that would require bubbling of the events the parent tree upwards which is madness in performance and would not really do any good to the actual `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanging` events : /
the actual properties do not change, its the childrens properties which do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got solved by using a hacky and not nice overhead way ...

the events will now get bubbled to the object-tree root ... which actually is not correct ... but solves the problem ...
that + a special converter that takes em ...

if somebody got a better solution, please answer